# removing timelines from a text (continuing a text without timelines)

Tags: python

I have a file which is a subtitle (sub.srt or a text file) of a movie. But I wonder if there is a short way to delete all line-numbers and time-lines of the file. For example

```
85
00:07:39,250 --> 00:07:41,469
We got to be smart.
We're a ways from being finished.

86
00:07:41,628 --> 00:07:43,380
I can do this all week.

87
00:07:43,546 --> 00:07:44,547
We're gonna.

 88
00:07:44,714 --> 00:07:49,352
We're like the Comanches,
little brother, raiding wherever we please
```

It must be turned out as

```
We got to be smart.
We're a ways from being finished.

I can do this all week.

We're gonna.

We're like the Comanches,
little brother, raiding wherever we please
```

or in a continuum shape:

```
We got to be smart. We're a ways from being finished. I can do this all week.  We're gonna.  We're like the Comanches, little brother, raiding wherever we please
```

Can python or anything programming language else reach us to this goal?

Comment: Any general-purpose programming language can be used ? What have you tried ? How did it fail ? Please note that StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: *Hint:* All lines that `startswith` digit have to be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the `line` starts with a `digit` and print only if it does not:

list.txt:

```
85
00:07:39,250 --> 00:07:41,469
We got to be smart.
We're a ways from being finished.

86
00:07:41,628 --> 00:07:43,380
I can do this all week.

87
00:07:43,546 --> 00:07:44,547
We're gonna.

 88
00:07:44,714 --> 00:07:49,352
We're like the Comanches,
little brother, raiding wherever we please
```

**Hence**:

```
with open("list.txt", 'r') as fp:
content = fp.readlines()
# you may also want to remove empty lines
content = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]
for line in content:
    if not line[0].isdigit():
        print(line)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
We got to be smart.
We're a ways from being finished.
I can do this all week.
We're gonna.
We're like the Comanches,
little brother, raiding wherever we please
```

**EDIT**:

Use `print(line, end = " ")` to get the output in a single line:

**OUTPUT**:

```
We got to be smart. We're a ways from being finished. I can do this all week. We're gonna. We're like the Comanches, little brother, raiding wherever we please
```